# How to convert Json to CSV and send it to big query or google cloud bucket

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, apache-nifi

I`m new to nifi and I want to convert big amount of json data to csv format.
This is what I am doing at the moment but it is not the expected result.

These are the steps:

processes to create access_token and send request body using InvokeHTTP(This part works fine I wont name the processes since this is the expected result) and getting the response body in json.

Example of json response:

```
    [
   {
      "results":[
         {
            "customer":{
               "resourceName":"customers/123456789",
               "id":"11111111"
            },
            "campaign":{
               "resourceName":"customers/123456789/campaigns/222456422222",
               "name":"asdaasdasdad",
               "id":"456456546546"
            },
            "adGroup":{
               "resourceName":"customers/456456456456/adGroups/456456456456",
               "id":"456456456546",
               "name":"asdasdasdasda"
            },
            "metrics":{
               "clicks":"11",
               "costMicros":"43068982",
               "impressions":"2079"
            },
            "segments":{
               "device":"DESKTOP",
               "date":"2021-11-22"
            },
            "incomeRangeView":{
               "resourceName":"customers/456456456/incomeRangeViews/456456546~456456456"
            }
         },
            {
            "customer":{
               "resourceName":"customers/123456789",
               "id":"11111111"
            },
            "campaign":{
               "resourceName":"customers/123456789/campaigns/222456422222",
               "name":"asdasdasdasd",
               "id":"456456546546"
            },
            "adGroup":{
               "resourceName":"customers/456456456456/adGroups/456456456456",
               "id":"456456456546",
               "name":"asdasdasdas"
            },
            "metrics":{
               "clicks":"11",
               "costMicros":"43068982",
               "impressions":"2079"
            },
            "segments":{
               "device":"DESKTOP",
               "date":"2021-11-22"
            },
            "incomeRangeView":{
               "resourceName":"customers/456456456/incomeRangeViews/456456546~456456456"
            }
         },
....etc....
      ]
   }
]
```

Now I am using:
===>SplitJson ($[*].results[*])==>JoltTransformJSON with this spec:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {

        "customer": {
            "id": "customer_id"
        },
        "campaign": {
            "id": "campaign_id",
            "name": "campaign_name"
        },
        "adGroup": {
            "id": "ad_group_id",
            "name": "ad_group_name"

        },
        "metrics": {
            "clicks": "clicks",
            "costMicros": "cost",
            "impressions": "impressions"
        },
        "segments": {
            "device": "device",
            "date": "date"
        },
        "incomeRangeView": {
            "resourceName": "keywords_id"
        }
    }
}]
```

==>> MergeContent( here is the problem which I don`t know how to fix)
Merge Strategy: Defragment
Merge Format: Binary Concatnation
Attribute Strategy Keep Only Common Attributes
Maximum number of Bins 5 (I tried 10 same result)
Delimiter Strategy: Text
Header: [
Footer: ]
Demarcator: ,

What is the result I get?
I get a json file that has parts of the json data
Example: I have 50k customer_ids in 1 json file so I would like to send this data into big query table and have all the ids under the same field "customer_id".

The MergeContent uses the split json files and combines them but I will still get 10k customer_ids for each file i.e. I have 5 files and not 1 file with 50k customer_ids

After the MergeContent I use ==>>ConvertRecord with these settings:
Record Reader JsonTreeReader (Schema Access Strategy: InferSchema)
Record Writer CsvRecordWriter (
Schema Write Strategy: Do Not Write Schema
Schema Access Strategy: Inherit Record Schema
CSV Format: Microsoft Excel
Include Header Line: true
Character Set UTF-8
)

==>>UpdateAttribute (custom prop: filename: ${filename}.csv) ==>> PutGCSObject(and put the data into the google bucket (this step works fine- I am able to put files there))

With this approach I am UNABLE to send data to big query(After MergeContent I tried using PutBigQueryBatch and used this command in bq sheel to get the schema I need:

```
bq show --format=prettyjson some_data_set.some_table_in_that_data_set | jq '.schema.fields'
```

I filled all the fields as needed and Load file type: I tried NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON or CSV if I converted it to CSV (I am not getting errors but no data is uploaded into the table)
)

What am I doing wrong? I basically want to map the data in such a way that each fields data will be under the same field name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick you are missing is using Records.

Instead of using X>SplitJson>JoltTransformJson>Merge>Convert>X, try just X>[JoltTransformRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-jolt-record-nar/1.15.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.jolt.record.JoltTransformRecord/index.html)>X with a JSON Reader and a CSV Writer. This skips a lot of inefficiency.

If you really need to split (and you should avoid splitting and merging unless totally necessary), you can use MergeRecord instead - again with a JSON Reader and CSV Writer. This would make your flow X>Split>Jolt>MergeRecord>X.

Comment: I use in splitJson $[*].results[*] and then the rest.
If I get the response and then JoltTransformRecord then the spec should be for the response it self correct?
This idea sounds very usful! I`m trying it right now - Thank you!

Comment: I am getting an error: unable to transform standartFlowFileRecord[uuid=...]. [resource claim=standartresourceclaim[id=...] du to error transforming the first record

I managed to make it work only after the split.
When I get the data I get it as stated in the example json response above. 
I understand that the jolt spec should be some thing else but what exactly?

Comment: This is what the spec is returning:
{
 "customer_id": ["234234", "34234"],
 "campaign_id": ["234234", "2"],34234
 "campaign_name": ["'aaaa", "'aaaaa"],
 "ad_group_id": ["12312", "12312"],
 "ad_group_name": ["aaa", "aaa"],
 "clicks": ["11", "11"],
 "cost": ["243423", "234234"],
 "impressions": ["2079", "2079"],
 "device": ["DESKTOP", "DESKTOP"],
 "date": ["2021-11-22", "2021-11-22"]
}

Comment: So you could start with a JoltTransformJson to Shift the contents of the `results` array back to top level - so rather than `[ { "results" : [ {...}, {...}. {...}, ... ] } ]` you would have just `[ {...}, {...}. {...}, ... ]`. This results in 1 FlowFile with all results as items in a flat top level array. Now you can use JoltTransformRecord, which will evaluate against each item in the array individually.

Try using https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ to work on your JOLT spec to get the result you need.

Comment: thank you for the advice- so that is what i actually did and now have [{...},{...}...{...}]. I am able to convert it to csv using convertRecord as next step. the only problem now is that the first line has the headers and when i push the data into bq it read them instead as headers, as the first row and the headers in bq how auto generated to random values

Comment: The CSV Writer has a property `Include Header Line` which defaults to `true`. Try setting that to `false` and it should get rid the header line :)

Comment: I tried it and it does work - the only thing I have to create the table from scratch with correct schema before I push the data.

Is there a fix for this to make it auto with out creating the table before hand?
also how do I push data into big query? this does work for bucket.
I provided correct schema to big query and I get errors for null pointer. I wrote "Mode":"Nullable"